# Windows Phone Textbox - Keyboard does not show

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-runtime, keyboard, windows-phone-8.1

I have a very simple scenario where I can focus an editable text box, the cursor appears inside the field, bt the keyboard will not show.

I have replicated this in a small sample app (Windows Phone 8.1 - Universal App).  Very easy to recreate.

Create an 8.1 universal app.  In the MainPage for phone add a text box and a button.  The code for the button just sets the textbox to NOT read only.  The default state of the textbox is ReadOnly.

Run app, select edit and then select the field.  Cursor is present and keyboard opens.  Close app.

Failure scenario:

1. Open app, touch read only text field.  Note: No cursor is in box as it is read only.
2. Select Edit button.  Tap the text field.  Cursor is focused into field, but keyboard does not appear.  I have a sample app with this behavior.

Any Resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Windows Phone 8.1 which is fixed in current builds of Windows 10 Mobile.

Unfortunately I don't see any good workarounds for this on Windows Phone 8.1 other than "don't do that". Instead of switching a TextBox into and out of IsReadOnly mode try swapping between two TextBoxes (or a TextBox and a TextBlock).

Comment: Also recreating the control in each state or using two pages, one for view and one for edit.

Comment: Note that I can still reproduce the described behavior in the current Insider build of Windows 10 Mobile, 10586.11. It acts exactly as described by op, but I don't even need to set IsReadOnly or IsEnabled. I run the app, then go out, then come back and weird stuff starts happening in my WP8.1 app. The cursor disappears completely, and if I have multiple textboxes in the app, it's unclear which one is available for writing, as when I cycle through them, they all get "focus", but might not actually get the actual writing focus, and the keyboard might not show.

Comment: That's a different issue. I've filed a bug to track it. In the future you can do so yourself via the Windows Feedback app.

Comment: I see... Thanks for filing it, it is fixed now in 10586.29.